# Why my code doesn't work? - Getting user input to initiate a for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, variable-assignment, user-input

So I have this Java assignment, where I must create a program, where if the user enters "initiate" it begins the for loop, which will print "initiated" 100 times. I've searched my code for errors, but can't find any. Please help :)

Thanks in advance.

```
       package container;

        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Assignment1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x = 0;

        String checker = "initiate";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();     
        if(input == checker){

            for(x=0;x<=100;x++){

                System.out.println("Initiated");

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, use the `equals` method to compare strings:

```
if(checker.equals(input))
```

However, also, your `for` loop will print `Initiated` 101 times, for values of `x` from 0 through 100.  Replace

```
for(x=0;x<=100;x++)
```

with

```
for(x=0;x<100;x++)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should compare Strings using `equals` instead of `==`

```
if (input.equals(checker))
```

Comment: The tutorials i was reading never mentioned any of these methods, you have opened a door for me :) thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(input == checker){
```

should be

```
 if(input.equals(checker)){
```

Use `equals()` method to check if two string objects are equal. `==` operator in case of Strings(Objects in general) checks if two references refer to the same object

- [**How do I compare strings in Java?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `input.equals(checker)` instead of `input == checker`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(input == checker)
```

compares if these two variables have the same object reference. Ie: point to the same object.

```
if(input.equals(checker))
```

checks if input has the same content as checker. That is why it's not working :)